# Неправильное расположение фреймов по отношению к кнопкам в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Друзья! Желаю доброго дня! Подскажите пожалуйста не могу разобраться почему вторая колонка с фреймами (текстом) располагается только напротив кнопки Ф1, а остальные кнопки смещаются вниз, требуется чтобы каждый фрейм был на против каждой кнопки от от Ф1 до Ф5. Спасибо буду очень благодарен!

```
from tkinter import *
class odin:
    def win1():
        global tk
        tk = Tk()
        tk.title("Cтарт")
        tk.geometry("100x70")
        tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        x = (tk.winfo_screenwidth() - tk.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
        y = (tk.winfo_screenheight() - tk.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
        tk.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        btn = Button(tk, text="Старт", height=4, width=20, command = close)
        btn.pack(side=LEFT)
        tk.mainloop()
def close():
    tk.destroy()
    wind()


def wind():
    global zk
    zk = Tk()
    zk.title("Финиш")
    zk.geometry("450x425")
    x = (zk.winfo_screenwidth() - zk.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    y = (zk.winfo_screenheight() - zk.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    zk.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    fram1 = Frame(zk,bg='black',bd=1)
    fram2 = Frame(zk, bg='black', bd=1)
    fram3 = Frame(zk, bg='black', bd=1)
    fram4 = Frame(zk, bg='black', bd=1)
    fram5 = Frame(zk, bg='black', bd=1)
    lbn1 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
    lbn2 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
    lbn3 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
    lbn4 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
    lbn5 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
    btn1 = Button(zk, text="Ф1", height=4, width=20)
    btn2 = Button(zk, text="Ф2", height=4, width=20)
    btn3 = Button(zk, text="Ф3", height=4, width=20)
    btn4 = Button(zk, text="Ф4", height=4, width=20)
    btn5 = Button(zk, text="Ф5", height=4, width=20)
    btn6 = Button(zk, text="Назад", height=4, width=20, command = nazad)
    btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    btn2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    btn3.grid(row=3, column=1)
    btn4.grid(row=4, column=1)
    btn5.grid(row=5, column=1)
    btn6.grid(row=6, column=1)
    fram1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    fram2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    fram3.grid(row=3, column=2)
    fram4.grid(row=4, column=2)
    fram5.grid(row=5, column=2)
    lbn1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    lbn1.insert(1.0, 'Здания, предназначенные для постоянного проживания и временного пребывания людей')
   lbn2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    lbn2.insert(2.0, 'Здания зрелищных и культурно-просветительных учреждений')
    lbn3.grid(row=3, column=2)
    lbn3.insert(3.0, 'Здания организаций по обслуживанию населения')
    lbn4.grid(row=4, column=2)
    lbn4.insert(4.0, 'Здания образовательных организаций, научных и проектных организаций, органов управления учреждений')
    lbn5.grid(row=5, column=2)
    lbn5.insert(5.0, 'Здания производственного или складского назначения')
    zk.mainloop()

def nazad():
    zk.destroy()
    odin1.win1()


def stop():
    zk.destroy()

    odin1 = odin
    odin1.win1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание, все текстовые поля вы помещаете в один и тот же фрейм, который располагается напротив первой кнопки:

```
zk = Tk()
...
fram1 = Frame(zk,bg='black',bd=1)
...
# Везде родителем указан fram1
lbn1 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn2 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn3 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn4 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn5 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
...
btn1.grid(row=1, column=1)
...
fram1.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Исправляем:

```
lbn1 = Text(fram1, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn2 = Text(fram2, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn3 = Text(fram3, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn4 = Text(fram4, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbn5 = Text(fram5, width=30, height=4, fg='black', wrap=WORD)
```

Получается:

[image: Скриншот]